# Segmentation Error in allocating memory for array in c

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int main()
{
    int *ptr;
    int n,i=3;
    printf("Enter number of elements you want in array:");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    ptr=(int *)malloc(n*sizeof(n));
    if(ptr=NULL)
    {
        printf("Memory Not Allocated!!");
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Memory allocation succesful\n");
        int *arr;
        printf("write elements here\n");
        for(arr=ptr;arr<ptr+n;arr++)
        {
            scanf("%d",arr);
            printf("Hello world");
            printf("\n");
        }
        for(arr=ptr;arr<ptr+n;arr++)
        {
            printf("%d",*arr);
        }
        free(ptr);
    return 0;
    }
}
```

Whenever I run this code so while taking input it stops working. So I tried in later checked in an online compiler, it gives Segmentation Fault.

Please help me out!

Comment: `ptr=(int *)malloc(n*sizeof(n));`While it is by pure accident the correct size, you should not use `sizeof(n)` but `sizeof(*ptr)` to allocate memory. In most cases the type of the number of elements is not related to the size of elements to be stored. And you should not cast the return value from `malloc`.

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```
if(ptr=NULL)
```

Should be:

```
if(ptr==NULL)
```

Otherwise, `ptr` gets assigned the value of `NULL` and `ptr=NULL` evaluates to false.  Hence, the *else clause* is run immediately after the `ptr` is assigned to `NULL`.

One other thing, to improve the readability of your for-loop, this is a bit more readable:

```
   for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
   {
       scanf("%d",&ptr[i]);
```

The `for` statement is standard for saying, `loop n times`.  The use of `&ptr[i]` (or `ptr+i`) makes it a lot more obvious which address is being referenced.

Comment: Actually, it DOESN"T get skipped -- it sets the pointer to null, then evaluates as false, going into the else branch with a now-null pointer, which crashes...

Comment: Will downvoter care to explain his dislike?

Comment: @ChrisDodd Yeah! I get it now :)

Comment: @selbie here's another downvote, a blatant typo is off-topic on Stack Overflow, and this question has been answered a thousand times already.